# How to fix apt-get update in Debian Lenny so that PostgreSql 9.1 can installed

Tags: linux, postgresql, debian, postgresql-9.1, lenny

I tried

```
apt-get update
```

on Debian Lenny but got error below.
How to fix this so that PostgreSql 9.1 can installed ?

```
root:~# apt-get update
Ign http://security.debian.org etch/updates Release.gpg
Get:1 http://archive.debian.org Debian-4.0 Release.gpg [1033B]
Get:2 http://archive.debian.org etch-backports Release.gpg [189B]
Ign http://security.debian.org etch/updates Release
Hit http://archive.debian.org Debian-4.0 Release
Ign http://security.debian.org etch/updates/main Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.debian.org etch/updates/main Sources/DiffIndex
Hit http://archive.debian.org etch-backports Release
Ign http://security.debian.org etch/updates/main Packages
Ign http://archive.debian.org Debian-4.0/main Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.debian.org Debian-4.0/contrib Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.debian.org Debian-4.0/non-free Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.debian.org etch/updates/main Sources
Get:3 http://archive.debian.org etch-backports Release [72,9kB]
Err http://security.debian.org etch/updates/main Packages
  404 Not Found [IP: 212.211.132.250 80]
Err http://security.debian.org etch/updates/main Sources
  404 Not Found [IP: 212.211.132.250 80]
Hit http://archive.debian.org Debian-4.0/main Packages
Hit http://archive.debian.org Debian-4.0/contrib Packages
Ign http://archive.debian.org etch-backports Release
Hit http://archive.debian.org Debian-4.0/non-free Packages
Ign http://archive.debian.org etch-backports/main Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.debian.org etch-backports/contrib Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.debian.org etch-backports/non-free Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://archive.debian.org etch-backports/main Packages
Hit http://archive.debian.org etch-backports/contrib Packages
Hit http://archive.debian.org etch-backports/non-free Packages
Fetched 73,1kB in 0s (90,3kB/s)
Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/etch/updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404 Not Found [IP: 212.211.132.250 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/etch/updates/main/source/Sources.gz  404 Not Found [IP: 212.211.132.250 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
9AA38DCD55BE302B
W: Conflicting distribution: http://archive.debian.org Debian-4.0 Release (expected Debian-4.0 but got etch)
W: GPG error: http://archive.debian.org etch-backports Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EA8E8B2116BA136C
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

sources.list contains:

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian Debian-4.0 main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ etch/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ etch/updates main
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-backports etch-backports main contrib non-free
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like you have etch repos in a lenny distro, 
so why not update your source.list with lenny repos:

```
###### Debian Main Repos
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ lenny main contrib non-free 

###### Debian Update Repos
deb http://security.debian.org/ lenny/updates main contrib non-free 
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ lenny-proposed-updates main contrib non-free
```

This probably fix the problem but postgresql 9.1 is only available in testing distro, so you can try add this line

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free
```

in the file /etc/apt/source.list

Also add

```
Package: *
Pin: release n=testing
Pin-Priority: 500
```

in /etc/apt/preferences

doing this you will have all the packages for the testing version, but they're not going to be installed unless you specify it, so run

```
apt-get update
apt-get install <package name>=<version>
```

for example

```
apt-get install postgresql=9.1+129
```

you can check the different versions with

```
apt-cache showpkg postgresql
```

Comment: btw i recommend you change to squeeze distro, is the new stable debian version